# Rewrite URL with a specific query string

Tags: wordpress

I need to do opposite of Rewrite rule for WORD PRESS

http://www.mydomain.com/promo1

/promo1, /promo2 case insensitive

must redirect 301 goto:

http://www.mydomain.com/promo1More?customvar1=AA&customvar2=BB&customvar3=CC

all these promo1, promo2... must be in 2 dimensional array second column of the array is the physical static page

but is important the target page must call with ? querystring and custom vars

Comment: Its quite unclear, what is customvar1? 2, 3 ?

Comment: serialNumber=AA&marketing=emailcompain

Comment: follow last part of this tutorial http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/the-rewrite-api-the-basics--wp-25474

Comment: Where does the customvar1, customvar2 and customevar3 variables come from?

Comment: customvar1, customvar2 and customevar3  are hardcode by us

Comment: anyway I have no too much time and I decide to use pure redirect   wp_redirect( $redirect2  , 301);
    exit;